# Excel odd @ formula in table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel workbook from ancient times. A table with header and rows of data are recorded in it. I insert a new column next to an existing one and start typing in an `if` formula in the first row.

```
=if(
```

The if statement will compare the adjacent cell "Gender" in the row, so I clicked the adjacent cell to get its cell reference to continue the formula.

But lo and behold, the cell reference that is automatically entered into the formula turned out to be `[@[Gender]]` rather than the usual cell reference i.e. `B5`. After that I then continue to complete the formula...

```
=if([@[Gender]]="M", "Male", "Female")
```

... and then hit enter to confirm the change. Then immediately all the rows beneath the formula cell get updated with the same formula. I didn't have to manually copy the formula to other rows.

What is the feature that is being used as described above?

Answer (score 1):

It's [structured references](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-structured-references-in-Excel-table-formulas-75fb07d3-826a-449c-b76f-363057e3d16f) in table formulas. Here's more [KB](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) on it.